文字列リテラルエラーが出てしまいました
Jupyter Notebookを使って、以下の記事の内容を練習しています。
【図解で解説】LightGBMの仕組みとPythonでの実装を見ていこう！
以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。
文字列リテラルが閉じられていないのでしょうか。
エラーメッセージ:
 Cell In[121], line 59
    category")
            ^
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 59)

ソースコード:
def data_pre(df):
    nonnull_list = []
    for col in df.columns:
        nonnull = df[col].count()
        if nonnull == 0:
            nonnull_list.append(col)
    df = df.drop(nonnull_list, axis=1)

    df = df.drop("市区町村名", axis=1)

    df = df.drop("種類", axis=1)

    dis = {
        "30分?60分":45,
        "1H?1H30":75,
        "2H?":120,
        "1H30?2H":105
    }
    df["最寄駅：距離（分）"] = df["最寄駅：距離（分）"].replace(dis).astype(float)

    df["面積（㎡）"] = df["面積（㎡）"].replace("2000㎡以上", 2000).astype(float)


    y_list = {}
    for i in df["建築年"].value_counts().keys():
        if "平成" in i:
            num = float(i.split("平成")[1].split("年")[0])
            year = 33 - num
        if "令和" in i:
            num = float(i.split("令和")[1].split("年")[0])
            year = 3 - num
        if "昭和" in i:
            num = float(i.split("昭和")[1].split("年")[0])
            year = 96 - num
        y_list[i] = year
    y_list["戦前"] = 76
    df["建築年"] = df["建築年"].replace(y_list)

    year = {
        "年第１四半期": ".25",
        "年第２四半期": ".50",
        "年第３四半期": ".75",
        "年第４四半期": ".99"
    }
    year_list = {}
    for i in df["取引時点"].value_counts().keys():
        for k, j in year.items():
            if k in i:
                year_rep = i.replace(k, j)
        year_list[i] = year_rep
    df["取引時点"] = df["取引時点"].replace(year_list).astype(float)
    
    for col in ["都道府県名", "地区名", "最寄駅：名称", "間取り", "建物の構造", "用途", "今後の利用目的", "都市計画", "改装", "取引の事情等"]:
                df[col] = df[col].astype("category")
    
    return df
    
df = data_pre(df)


line 59 というのはどこ？

その参照記事の最初のimport等が何か間違って入力されているか、実行されていないか、他に参照記事以外の処理をやっていて、その残滓が悪影響しているとかが考えられるのでは？ いったんnotebookを終了して新規にまっさらなnotebookを立ち上げて参照記事の内容の入力と確認だけを行ってみてはどうでしょう？

WebSurfer さん 下から5行目です。

kunif さん 丁寧にありがとうございます！やってみます。

新たなnotebookでCHATGDPにコードを直してもらいました。
